# Mysql - Create view with case and count

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a view with CASE and COUNT from this two tables

```
t_jobs

| job_id |
+--------+
|   1    |
|   2    |
|   3    |
|   4    |

t_emails 

| email_id | job_id | email_log |
+----------+--------+-----------+
|    1     |   1    |    OK     |
|    2     |   1    |   ERROR   |
|    3     |   2    |   ERROR   |
|    4     |   3    |    OK     |
```

The result should be this

```
view_jobs

| job_id | email_check | email_total |
+--------+-------------+-------------+
|    1   |     1       |      2      |
|    2   |     1       |      1      |
|    3   |     0       |      1      |
|    4   |     0       |      0      |
```

I'm trying in this way but with no success

```
SELECT
  j.job_id,
  CASE WHEN MAX( e.email_log != 'OK' ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END email_check
  COUNT( e.email_log ) AS email_total
FROM t_jobs j
  LEFT OUTER JOIN `t_emails` `e` ON `j`.`job_id` = `e`.`job_id`
GROUP BY
  j.job_id;
```

Can you tell me how can I do? 
Thanks

Comment: Can you explain the logic of the column email_check?

Comment: Why does `job_id` 4 has `email_check` = 1? I thought it should be `0`.

Comment: @GMB - Sorry my mistake. I edited it.

Comment: Will you explain the 1s and 0s in the column email_check?

Comment: Your code returns your expected results. What is your question?

Comment: @Gus - Your code is returning result which you are expecting. Only thing is: you forgot comma after `email_check` and before `COUNT(e.email_log)`

Comment: Sorry people. I've a syntax error and my code works. Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need a simple conditional aggregation -

```
SELECT j.job_id,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN e.email_log <> 'OK' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) email_check,
       COUNT(e.email_log) AS email_total
FROM t_jobs j
LEFT OUTER JOIN `t_emails` `e` ON `j`.`job_id` = `e`.`job_id`
GROUP BY j.job_id;
```

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya, Do you meant to remove `ELSE` clause as i did?

Comment: That doesn't make any differences.

Comment: It is all about following a clearer syntax to understand; so that anyone can read it and figure out what is happening. `ELSE NULL` explicitly makes it clear that dont count if there is a no match. I prefer clearer queries at the cost of slight verbosity, because this generally avoids making mistakes like `ELSE 0` ;)

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya, Completely agree on this and will surely try to follow the same in future. Minor things like these clearly shows the difference between an IITian and a non-IITian.

Answer (score 0):

You just forgot a comma(,) at end of second column.
I also modified your condition a little bit.
Here email_check 1 denotes that job_id has error
0 denotes it has no error.

```
 SELECT
      j.job_id,
      CASE WHEN MIN( e.email_log ) = 'error'  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as email_check,
      COUNT( e.email_log ) AS email_total
    FROM t_jobs j
      LEFT OUTER JOIN `t_emails` `e` ON `j`.`job_id` = `e`.`job_id`
    GROUP BY
      j.job_id;
```